# How to filter and subset a dataframe based on another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Whilst there are many questions similar to this, I haven't been able to find the answer to this question specifically in R, so I am not sure where to start with this. I have 2 datasets:

Data1:

```
Chr Start   End   rssnp1        Type    gene
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE
1   1257536 1257436 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4
1   1252343 1252343 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1254841 1254841 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1256703 1267404 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1371824 1371824 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1372591 1372591 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
```

Data2:

```
    gene
    CPEB4
    GML
    TBX2
    PNKD
    JMJD1C
    SKI
    MYH11
```

Data2 is an output from machine learning (genes which have been classed as  affecting a disease).

I am looking to select a gene from Data2, find it in Data1 and specifically find the gene row which has the Type column as 'Sentinel', and then filter Data1 based that sentinel genes' rssnp1 column.

For example if I were searching for the CPEB4 gene from Data1 and found its Sentinel gene rssnp1 (rs2286773) to filter by the output is:

```
Chr Start   End    rssnp1       Type     gene
1   1243933 1243934 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACAP3
1   1254436 1254436 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4
```

So far I have looked at using merge, filter() and subset(), but as I have many steps should I be trying to use these in a for loop? Are there better functions for this?

I am new to R so haven't made much progess, for example I've tried merging the datasets:

```
merged <- merge(data1, data2, by='gene', all='TRUE')
```

This works with then in just excel filtering manually, but ideally I'd like to automate this further, so any advice/help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you would like to pass each gene from data2 and get their corresponding data from data1. I hope the below code helps.

```
library(dplyr)
getFromData1 <- function(geneFromData2 = NULL) {
  if (is.null(geneFromData2)) return()
  geneSentinelSNP <- (data1 %>% filter(Type == "Sentinel" & gene == geneFromData2))$rssnp1
  data1 %>% filter(rssnp1 == geneSentinelSNP)
}

getFromData1(geneFromData2 = "CPEB4")
```

You can also call the `getFromData1` function in a `lapply` so that you get a list of data frames, one for each gene from data2.

```
lapply(data2$gene, getFromData1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to do a group by 'rssnp1' after a `full_join` and `filter` for `any` values as 'Sentinel' in 'Type'

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(data1, data2, by = 'gene') %>% 
     group_by(rssnp1) %>% 
     filter(any(Type == "Sentinel")) #or
     #filter("Sentinel" %in% Type)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   rssnp1 [1]
#    Chr   Start     End rssnp1    Type     gene 
#  <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>
#1     1 1244733 1244734 rs2286773 LD_SNP   ACE  
#2     1 1252336 1252336 rs2286773 Sentinel CPEB4
```

---

Or using the OP's code, it can be further extended with `ave`

```
i1 <-  with(merged, ave(Type %in% "Sentinel", rssnp1, FUN = any))
merged[i1,]
```

#### data

```
data1 <- structure(list(Chr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Start = c(1244733L, 1257536L, 1252336L, 1252343L, 1254841L, 
1256703L, 1269246L, 1370168L, 1371824L, 1372591L), End = c(1244734L, 
1257436L, 1252336L, 1252343L, 1254841L, 1267404L, 1269246L, 1370168L, 
1371824L, 1372591L), rssnp1 = c("rs2286773", "rs301159", "rs2286773", 
"rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", 
"rs301159"), Type = c("LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "Sentinel", "LD_SNP", 
"LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP"), 
    gene = c("ACE", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", 
    "CPEB4", "GLUPA1", "GLUPA1", "GLUPA1")),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

data2 <- structure(list(gene = c("CPEB4", "GML", "TBX2", "PNKD", "JMJD1C", 
"SKI", "MYH11")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```